# OneHotEncoder failing after combining dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I have a model that runs successfully.

When I tried to predict using it, it was failing due to the fact that after OneHotEncoding, the test set had more columns than the train.

After some reading I found where I need to concat the two df's first, OneHotEncode, then split them apart.

1. Added a 'temp' column to the train data set with value 'train'.
2. Added a 'temp' column to the test data set with value 'test'.
3. This is so that I can split the df apart later using boolean indexing like this:

```
X = temp_df[temp_df['temp'] == 'train']
X2 = temp_df[temp_df['temp'] == 'test']
```

4. Vertically concat the two df's.
5. Verify the shape of the new combined df.
6. Change all columns to type 'category' except 'temp', which is object:

```
basin                    category
region                   category
lga                      category
extraction_type_class    category
management               category
quality_group            category
quantity                 category
source                   category
waterpoint_type          category
cluster                  category
temp                       object
```

7. Now I am simply trying to OneHotEncode like I did before.  I choose only categorical columns:

```
cat_ix = temp_df.select_dtypes(include=['category']).columns
```

8. And I try to apply with:

```
ct = ColumnTransformer([('o', OneHotEncoder(), cat_ix)], remainder='passthrough')
temp_df = ct.fit_transform(temp_df)
```

It fails on the temp_df = ct.fit_transform(temp_df) line.

These identical steps worked perfectly before I added the temp column and concat'd the two df's.

The exact error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose\_column_transformer.py", line 778, in _hstack
    converted_Xs = [
  File "C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose\_column_transformer.py", line 779, in <listcomp>
    check_array(X, accept_sparse=True, force_all_finite=False)
  File "C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 738, in check_array
    array = np.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1993, in __array__
    return np.asarray(self._values, dtype=dtype)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'train'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose\_column_transformer.py", line 783, in _hstack
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: For a sparse output, all columns should be a numeric or convertible to a numeric.
```

Why is it complaining about 'train'?  That is in the 'temp' column which is being excluded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the traceback doesn't reference `OneHotEncoder`, it's all the `ColumnTransformer`.  You're trying to pass through the `temp` column, which gets tacked onto the one-hot-encoded *sparse matrix* in the method `_hstack`, and the second error message is the more relevant one.  It cannot stack a string-type array onto a numeric sparse array (which leads to the first error message).

If the sparse matrix isn't too large, you can just force it to be dense by using `sparse_threshold=0` in the `ColumnTransformer` or `sparse=False` in the `OneHotEncoder`.  If it is too large for memory (or you'd prefer the sparse matrices), you could use a 0/1 indicator for the train/test split instead of the strings `"train", "test"`.